Span of intersection of linear subspace and simplex
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
Let $V$ be a linear subspace of $\R^d$. Denote as $\Delta$ the simplex in $\R^d$, namely the set $$\Delta = \{v\in\R^d_{\geq 0}\;:\;\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^d v_i=1\}\,.$$
Denote as $\Delta^\circ$ the interior of $\Delta$, namely $\Delta\cap\R^d_{>0}$. Now, assume that $V\cap \Delta^\circ\neq\varnothing$. Is it true that $$\mathrm{span}(V\cap\Delta) = V\,?$$
I know that this is not true if one only asks that $V\cap \Delta\neq\varnothing$ (without considering the interior). Indeed, in $\R^3$ we could have $V=\mathrm{span}\{(1,0,0),(0,1,-1)\}$. Clearly, $V\cap\Delta = \{1,0,0\}$ and so things cannot work. However it seems to me that any counter example of this kind has to play with the fact that $V$ is only intersecting the boundary of $\Delta$. So I believe that asking for non-empty intersection with the interior would be enough to ensure the required property. It does not seem super trivial to show though.

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
$\newcommand{\span}{\mathrm{span}}$
This is actually true. Indeed, first one can notice that if $B$ is a non-empty open ball in $\R^n$, and $V\cap B\neq\varnothing$, then $\span(V\cap B) = V$. Then, if $V\cap\Delta^\circ\neq\varnothing$, we have that there is an open ball $B\subset\R^d_{\geq 0}$ such that $V\cap B\neq\varnothing$. It follows that
$$V=\span(V) \supseteq\span(V\cap\Delta)=\span(V\cap\R^d_{\geq 0})\supseteq\span(V\cap B) = V\,.$$
